# Python try catch always raising error if previusly exception was raised

Tags: python-3.x

I have try-catch that behaved differently, Once an exception is raised, the next time the try-catch block is called, it's always raising an exception even if the params passed are valid

```
 class Some
   def some_method(variable_id: str):
      response = requests.request('https://...........)
      if response.status_code != 200:
          if response.status_code == 404:
              raise ClientError(
                '_NOT_FOUND', 'Consignment does not exist. Please provide a valid variable_id', 404)
           elif response.status_code == 400:
               raise ClientError(
                '_ALREADY_CANCELLED', f"Cannot print {variable_id}", 400)
            raise ClientError(
            'ERROR', "ERROR", 400)
       return response
```

try catch

```
 class Other:
    def __init__(self):
        self.error = False

    def somefunc(id: str):
        //id = '123' //working one
        try:
           response = Some().some_method(id)
           return self.error, response
        except Exception as e:
           self.error = True
           return error,[]
```

The weird thing is if I first called the try-catch using the id that the API check as valid, it will return the response in the try-catch block as expected. But when I replace the id with a value that the API is returning 400 status_code, it will always raise the 400 status code exception even if I called the try-catch block with the previous id that should return 200.

So I tried to print the `response.status_code`, it is correctly 200 for a valid id, and 400 for an invalid id, but I don't know why it always raises the exception after I call the try-catch block with an invalid id, and change again with a valid id instead of returning the response in `Some.some_method` class method.

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: You've removed too much, so we have to guess.  Can we assume the `requests.request` string somehow depends on `variable_id`?  How are you doing the looping?  Is it possible `id` doesn't get reset?

Comment: I print the response status code,its always correct, 400 for invalid and 200 for valid, but for some reason,it raises the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah my bad. I need to reset the error

```
 def somefunc(id: str):
    //id = '123'
    try:
       response = Some().some_method(id)
       return self.error, response
    except Exception as e:
       self.error = True
       return error,[]
    finally:
       self.error = False
```